# Wandisco: Creating a new replication rule via REST

Tags: python, linux, rest, curl, wandisco

How can I make an http POST request to create a new replication rule using the Wandisco REST API? The link to the documentation is [here](http://docs.wandisco.com/bigdata/wdfusion/#examples). The endpoint might look similar to this: http://wandiscofusionURL.com:8083/fusion/ ....

I don't need help with using Curl/Python requests. But I am not sure what the URL endpoint should be.

I don't see an available REST method to create a new replication rule. However I've been told that it's possible to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to create a new replication rule in Fusion is to read in the required fields via XML, so something like this:

vi create_rule.xml (Full schema can be found by reviewing ReplicatedDirectoryDTO)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<replicatedDirectory>
    <uri>/replicated/path/name</uri>
    <membershipId>GUID_FOR_MEMBERSHIP</membershipId>
    <familyRepresentativeId>
        <nodeId>GUID_OF_CURRENT_NODE_ID</nodeId>
    </familyRepresentativeId>
</replicatedDirectory>
```

- To find membershipId:

  - curl -X get $hostname:8082/fusion/memberships |xmllint -format - |grep membershipIdentity (use surrounding information to identify the correct one if more than one - Ignore any called “ECO-MEMBERSHIP-X etc)
- To Find nodeId:  curl -X get $hostname:8082/fusion/nodes (Both nodes displayed - use local one with matching hostname).

Then create Rule:

curl -s -X POST -d@create_rule.xml -H "Content-Type: application/xml" http://$hostname:8082/fusion/fs

Let us know if you need any more info.

Ian

Comment: Oh wow thank you... I will try in the AM at work and get back... will give you credit for sure

Comment: I think you're right... but what do should I do if there are many MembershipIDs? Several say ECO-MEMBERSHIP which I will ignore as per your instructions, but there are still 8 more membership IDs??? It's hard to tell which server they belong too, even though I am making the GET requests to a single server.

Comment: I'm on the road today and not near a running instance I can check on, but I thought there was an obvious field in the response to identify it. I'm probably wrong.


If you know a path that is in an existing Membership you want to use, you can call this endpoint and get the membershipId from the response 

`GET <server>:<port>/fusion/fs?path=/path`

If you're still stuck I'll run up an instance of Fusion and test it for you.

Comment: Yup searching via the path was exactly what I needed... that narrows down the membershipId as well as the nodeId... thanks